# How to setup ReactJs props validation with JSDoc in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, react-props, jsdoc

Currently, am writing my react components like this

```
/**
 * Textbox input component
 * @param {{
 * label: string
 * }} props
 *
 */
function Textbox(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="txtbox">{props.label}</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtbox" />
    </>
  );
}
```

I am giving in my props and expected types in the JSDoc comment. But VSCode still throws problems(erros) because eslint compilation is not seeing proptypes.

[ESLint Problem/Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sllhn.png)

I know i can disable eslint , but can't i make eslint work with the JSDoc comment?

If i add this , the error is gone. But this would mean, i have to write proptypes two times for each component.

```
Textbox.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

What is the ideal way to do PropsValidation with JSDoc?